For a curve to be smooth, it is necessary that its derivative is never equal to $0$. Why? (Complex Analysis, Curves in the complex plane)
I have a question about curves in the complex plane.

A parametrized curve is a function $z(t)$ which maps a closed interval $[a,b]\subset\mathbb{R}$ to the complex plane. We shall impose regularity conditions on the parametrization which are always verified in the situations that occur in this book. We say that the parametrized curve is smooth if $z'(t)$ exists and is continuous on $[a,b]$, and $z'(t)\neq 0$ for $t\in [a,b]$.

If $\dot{z}(t)$ exists and is continuous on $[a,b]$, then $\int_{a}^{b} f(z(t))\dot{z}(t)dt$ exists.
For a curve to be smooth, it is necessary that its derivative is never equal to $0$.
Why?
Let $z(t)=t^3+|t|^3i$ for $t\in [-1,1]$.
Then, $\dot{z}(t)$ exists and is continuous but $\dot{z}(0)=0$.
And this curve bends at a right angle at $t=0$.
So, if we say this curve is smooth, I feel strange.
But is there any serious problem if we say this curve is smooth in complex function theory?

It's been a while since I've done complex analysis but I can leave you with an example. consider the curve $(t^2,t^3)$. Although It appears to be smooth, its derivative is 0 at $t=0$ and if you graph it, it is fairly clear to see it is not smooth.

@Nic thank you very much for your comment.

@underflow thank you very much for your comment. I feel the curve with $a=0$ and $b=0$ is not smooth.

The condition simply excludes possibility, that the velocity assumes a value of zero and reverses sign possibly twice or some multiples  of 2.
With a non-monotone parametrization, parts of the curve my be passed several times backwards and forwards.
Since the analytic definition and method to evaluate integrals is by reduction to 1-d integrals, all parametrization by a coordinatization have to be locally 1-1 invertible maps.
So one  avoids multiple counts in (Lebesgue) integrals, that are all defined as  limits of summation, independent of the order of summation (preservering measurability).
Of course its possible to implement integration with sign reverse and cancellation of backwards and forward segments in a partition of a curve, but this would imply the use  of the heavy artillery of topology and measure theory.

Roland F, thank you very much for your answer!

I think you are asking for the intuition behind this definition of a smooth curve. Maybe this will help:
Imagine you a riding a bike which has a device so that it is painting a line continuously on a pavement (e.g., the complex plane).
You can go straight ahead or steer right or left, but as long as you are moving forward and don't stop the turns will be smooth and rounded. The only way you can make a cusp or angled line is if you stop the bike.
This might be just a momentary stop, say if you started pedaling in the reverse - with this you can make a cusp in the curve.
Or, to put it another way, say you wanted to make a right angle on the pavement. To do this, you would have to stop the bike, pick it up and rotate it 90 degrees without moving the brush forward, and then start going forward again.
This example embodies the constraints: the derivative $z'(t)$ is the bike's velocity. By preventing the bike from coming to a stop, we are saying $z'(t) \neq 0$.
Also, just as the bike can't physically change its velocity discontinuously, we also have the constraint that $z'(t)$ is continuous. The reference above from complex-analysis.com has a nice picture a curve with a cusp.
As you say, your example curve, $z(t) = t^3+ i |t|^3$, makes a right-angle turn at zero, and is not smooth looking. This makes sense as the curve violates the requirements in definition for a smooth curve as you have above in one way or another.
Either, $z'(0)$ does not exist. The derivative of $|t|^3$ is usually taken as not defined at $0$ in analysis.
Or, as is done in some numerical packages, we can define $\frac{d}{dt} |t|$ at $t=0$ into existence. For example, we could define the value there to be $1$. (Note that the most common definition is for it to be $0$ as that is the average of $1$ and $-1$.) That is fine in many use-cases. But, in that case, while the derivative, $z'(t)$ now exists, it is not continuous; it jumps from $-1$ to $+1$ at $0$ so it violates the continuity requirement on  $z'(t)$ for $z(t)$ to be a smooth curve.

Chris L-M, thank you very much for your answer!
